# elixir-phoenix app keep exiting itself inside docker container with swarm mode

Tags: docker, elixir, phoenix-framework, docker-swarm

here is my production.Dockerfile

```
FROM elixir:1.6.5

RUN apt-get -y -qq update > /dev/null && \
  mix local.hex --force && \
  mix local.rebar --force && \
  ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.5 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.6

WORKDIR /phx_test

ADD phx_test.tar.gz .

EXPOSE 4001

ENTRYPOINT ["bin/phx_test"]

CMD ["console"]
```

production.docker-stack.yml

```
version: "3.6"

services:
  server:
    image: repo-name/webapp:0.0.2
    depends_on:
      - database
    networks:
      - backend
    ports:
      - "80:4001"
    deploy:
      replicas: 3

  database:
    image: postgres:10
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    secrets:
      - db-secret
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=pguser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/db-secret
      - POSTGRES_HOST=db-phx-test
      - POSTGRES_DB=phx-test-prod
    networks:
      - backend
networks:
  backend:

volumes:
  db-data:

secrets:
  db-secret:
    external: true
```

config/prod.secret.exs

```
config :phx_test, PhxTestWeb.EndPoint,
  http: [port: 4001],
  url: [host: "server", port: 4001],
  secret_key_base: "******"

config :phx_test, PhxTest.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapter.Postgres,
  username: "pguser",
  password: "super-secret-pw",
  hostname: "database",
  database: "phx-test-prod",
  port: 5432,
  pool_size: 15
```

I will use Phoenix + Absinthe for my next upcoming project and I want to dockerize my phoenix app, so I am using simple hello world phoenix app to test with it.

I could run the container from the image I built easily and access the hello world page without any problem, but after doing `stack deploy`, this happened

[image: Elixir console logs]

It seems to be exiting itself for some reason which I do not know how to solve this yet, anyone has this problem before please share some idea how to fix it.

Comment: never mind I just realized that I run the ``console`` instead of ``foreground`` at the ``CMD`` part. It is working fine now with ``forground``

Comment: You should use ADD, rather than COPY and RUN tar -xz -- ADD untars and unzips for you. And you should use ENTRYPOINT, not CMD. CMD is for parameters you want to pass to entrypoint.

Comment: You should add an answer explaining how you fixed this. It may be useful to someone else in future. Also, can you remove the image and replace it with a copy of the text from the error? People can't search into images when searching for the same problem.

Comment: @EngineerDollery Thanks very much for your comment, I will change from COPY to ADD as it has feature to extract local tar and thus reduces the layer of the image, and the ENTRYPOINT correct usage would be as you said.